# Theming WordPress the right way

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

What is the right way to customise a WordPress theme?

I would like to customise a WordPress theme so as to add features it lacks, but needed for my project.

It's not possible to solve this issue with the WordPress customizing tools.

More precisely I want to make a feature for Ope-Page menu with jQuery and customise CSS for it. I tried to make it in the CMS with Custom CSS/Javascript, but the code and styles are in conflict with the code and style of the theme, so it's need to be tested local.

What is the best practice to do it? Is it to install WP on localhost with XAMPP and code with PHPStorm?

Comment: just install WP on localhost with XAMPP

Comment: @Fiido93: *"Installing WordPress on localhost with XAMPP"* as the best practice, for WordPress theming? No! This is completely inappropriate.

Comment: lol @nyedidikeke i didn't say anything about best practice. lol i telling she or he just install wp on localhost using xampp.

Comment: @nyedidikeke read carefully next time thanks !

Comment: Well read @Fiido93; that was the message I got from your initial post. **Not to pull this further**; *you should consider making your comments/suggestions clearer so as to avoid any possible and or perceived misinterpretation(s)*.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make minor cosmetic CSS/Javascript changes to your theme is to create a child theme and add your changes there, that way when the Core theme is updated you won't lose your custom code.

The best way to do this is:

**1. The first step in creating a child theme is to create the child theme directory, which will be placed in wp-content/themes. It is recommended (though not required, especially if you're creating a theme for public use) that the name of your child theme directory is appended with '-child'. You will also want to make sure that there are no spaces in your child theme directory name, which may result in errors.**

**2. The next step is to create your child theme's stylesheet (style.css)**

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfifteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

You will need to edit the text above as it is all just example text.

**3.The final step is to enqueue the parent and child theme stylesheets.**

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

I have taken snippets from the Wordpress Codex, you can take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

This is the best way to customise a theme without editing the core parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practice to do it? Is it to install WP on localhost with XAMPP and code with PHPStorm?

The right practice doesn't have to do with the tools or software you make use of in theming process, but the approach for such a purpose.

As such, the best practice is: to [create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of the actual theme for that purpose.

A child theme comes with an added advantage: to enable customise further your theme without worrying much about possible future updates to your main theme overriding your custom changes.